# Stretch CSS navbar colors to edges of screen

Tags: html, css

My navbar is 1024px and floats in the middle of the screen.  I'm trying to carry the color of the navbar all the way to the left side of the screen.  On the right side of the navbar I would like to carry 5px of orange all the way to the right side of the screen.

```
.orangebar {
    background-color:#f36f21;
    height:5px;
}
```

I have created a dumbed down version of this problem in a jsFiddle (for quick editing).
http://jsfiddle.net/CKZhV

**Trying to achieve this:**
[image]

**Picture of problem:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the menu overflows `<body/>` and `<html/>`. As a result, your `.orangebar` just uses the width of `<body/>` which is a window width. That's why you don't see the rest if you scroll.

You could give it a `min-width`:

```
.orangebar {
    min-width: 1024px;
}
```

Basically I would not suggest it, but as you already have a fixed width for your menu, it does not matter.

Here is an [Update to your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CKZhV/1/)

Comment: I still need blue on the left side of the bar. But that is a step in the right direction!

Comment: @Chaddly, sorry, I don't understand what you mean with "I still need blue on the left side of the bar". Could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: Yes sorry its difficult to explain.  I have updated the picture in the question.  Let me know if that helps

Comment: @Chaddly, yeah, now I see. Well, that's way more complicated and depends very much on the exact result you want. I guess, your content should be centered in the window and the menu should be aligned left relative to the content?

Comment: That's correct.  In my jsFiddle I have the navbar positioned correctly.  I just need the blue to stretch from the edge of the nav bar to the left side of the screen.

Comment: Yeah, I see the problem and think of a solution, but I don't get a good one in mind. A `background-image` does not work because the menu could have different widths. A `display: table` **may** work, but for this you'll need additional html elements with no sense but design. Not an easy to solve problem here.

Comment: I understand, thank you for taking the time to wrap your mind around this.

Answer (score 1):

**A working version:** http://jsfiddle.net/CKZhV/3/ (see updated based on your input)

add this reset to your CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Saw your updated photo now your problem is clear. Edited my answer based on your new input.

You'd better give the container a min-width instead of a fixed width of 1024px and add a matching background color with the menu bar.

Then you can float it to left and float the content of it to the right. You won't need `margin:0 auto;` anymore.

**Here's an updated working version:** http://jsfiddle.net/CKZhV/10/

Comment: The blue is not stretching to the left side of the screen.  (resize the window you'll see what i mean)

Comment: It does stretch to the left side of the screen on all resizings: Chrome 25, FireFox 19, IE 9, Opera 12, Safari 5. Where are you viewing it?

Comment: Using Chrome 25.  I need blue to stretch left and orange to stretch right.  Check the updated picture

Comment: Do you mean you want the buttons to stay at their original place while the blue stretches to the left?

Comment: Yeah the navbar needs to remain in the 1024px box which is centered on the screen and text-align: left.  I simply need the blue color to stretch from the edge of the navbar to the left side of the screen.

Comment: Saw your new photo now your problem is clear. Edited my answer based on your new input.

Answer (score 1):

I edited your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/CKZhV/6/

```
#navbar {
    width:50%;
    text-align:right;
    float:right;
    background:#14325c;
    color:#fff;
}
```

revised http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/CKZhV/8/

Comment: Yes! But the menus are messed up now.

Comment: No sorry.  I'm starting to think this problem is not fixable without a site overhaul.

Comment: if my solution causes other items to become out of position then all you have to do is add a clear fix div below it. An easy fix.

Comment: Its actually way off base.  The right align is the main problem but after fiddling with it I just don't see it working correctly.  I'm going to have to leave it the way I had it.  I appreciate the help though.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use jQuery to make it work.

Summary: instead of using `margin` to center the menu, I adjusted the `padding-left` so that it would carry the `background-color`. I also changed some css, but that is less important that the js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <style>
                * {
                        margin:0;
                        padding:0;
                }
                .orangebar {
                        border-top:#f36f21 solid 5px;
                        width:100%;
                }
                #navbar {
                        width:20%;
                        background:#14325c;
                        height:39px;
                        margin:-5px 0 0 0;
                }
                .main-nav {
                        width:100%;
                        position:realtive;
                        background:#14325c;
                }
                .main-nav ul {
                        text-align:left;
                        display:block;
                        margin:0 auto;
                        padding:0;
                        list-style:none;
                        width:1024px;
                }
                .main-nav ul li {
                        display:inline-block;
                        margin:0;
                        position:relative;
                        padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
                        background:#14325c;
                        color:#fff;
                        cursor:pointer;
                        float:left;
                }
                .main-nav ul li:hover {
                        text-decoration:none;
                        background:#afb1b4;
                        color:#fff;
                }
                .main-nav ul li ul {
                        padding:0;
                        position:absolute;
                        top:34px;
                        left:0;
                        width:233px;
                        margin:0;
                        display:none;
                }
                .main-nav ul li:hover ul {
                        display:block;
                }
                .main-nav ul li ul li {
                        background:#afb1b4;
                        display:block;
                        color:#fff;
                }
                .main-nav ul li ul li:hover {
                        background:#d5d6d8;
                        color:#F36F21;
                        -moz-box-shadow:0px 2px 5px 2px rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.5);
                        -webkit-box-shadow:0px 2px 5px 2px rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.5);
                        box-shadow:0px 2px 5px 2px rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.5);
                }
        </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="orangebar">
    <div id="navbar">
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <nav class="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <li>BOARD OF TRUSTEES
                    <ul>
                        <li>Board Policy Manual</li>
                        <li>Monitoring Reports</li>
                        <li>Monthly Board Packets</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>RESOURCES
                    <ul>
                        <li>Academics</li>
                        <li>Student Services</li>
                        <li>Human Resources</li>
                        <li>Business Office</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- End Navbar -->
</div>
<!-- End Orangebar -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            $(function(){
                setLayout();
                $(window).resize(setLayout);
            });
            var setLayout = function(){
                $('#navbar').css({"padding-left": ($(window).width() - 1024) / 2 + 'px'});
            }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have a jsFiddle?  If not ill import it.

Comment: What are you expecting from them? The blue background carries to the left edge, that was the goal, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/CKZhV/4/). I have given .main-nav a width of 50% and a background color. This fiddle works but it doesn't go all the way to the screen as the parent div has `margin: 0 auto`.

If you remove the margin then you may get the desired solution. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/CKZhV/7/)